# extract name of worksheets and paste it in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

Can't develop a code that can loop through the worksheets extract the name of each worksheet and then paste it in a master workbook, this is what I've got so far

```
Sub date()
Dim day As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(SelectedFileItem)
Dim contador As Integer
contador = 2
Dim result As Workbook
Set result = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\apractica\Desktop\Macro\Durst\Resultados.xlsm")

For x = 1 To ws_num
    wb.Worksheets(x).Activate
    day = wb.Sheets(x).Name
    result.Cells(contador, 1).PasteSpecial xlPaste
    contador = contador + 1
Next
End Sub
```

wb = is the workbook with the worksheets I need to extract the name of each

result = is the master workbook where I want to copy the name of each worksheet

Comment: First step: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. `ws_num` is not declared.

Comment: `For Each ws in wb.Worksheeets`, `result.Worksheets(1).Cells(contador, 1).Value = ws.Name`.

Comment: `Dim ws_num As Integer`
`ws_num = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`

Comment: Please use the code I suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question out:

1. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. `ws_num` is not declared.
2. Loop over the collection of `wb.Worksheets`.
3. Make sure that you specify the worksheet before `.Cells(contador, 1)`. `result` is a `Workbook`.

```
For Each ws in wb.Worksheeets
    result.Worksheets(1).Cells(contador, 1).Value = ws.Name
    contador = contador + 1
Next
```